# vuejs check if computed property has changed using watch

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a product title that displays with a max of 2 lines and will overflow if the number of lines exceeds 2 and will display an ellipsis.

I am trying to detect if the ellipsis is active or not and I have the computed property `isEllipsisActive` thats returns true or false , however I need to watch this and show/hide div based on whether it is true or false when the condition of `isEllipsisActive` is true or false

```
<template>
 <div>
    <div
      ref="wrap"
      class="productTitle__titleWrapper">
    <h1
        ref="h1"
        class="productTitle__title">
      {{ productTitle }}
    </h1>
   <div v-if"el">show</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",

  data() {
    return {
       h1: null,
      wrap: null,
    };
  },

 mounted() {
this.$nextTick(() => {
  this.h1 = this.$refs.h1;
  this.wrap = this.$refs.wrap;
});
```

},

```
  computed: {
      isEllipsisActive() {
  if (!this.el) {
    console.log("Not initialized", this.el);
    return false;
  }
  return this.wrap.scrollHeight < this.h1.scrollHeight;
},
  },
};
</script>
```

css

```
 &__titleWrapper {
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-end;

  &__title {
      position: relative;
      display: block; /* Fallback for non-webkit */
      margin: rem-calc(-3.5px) 0 0 0;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Wouldn't `v-if="isEllipsisActive"` work for you ?

Comment: It doesn't update true or false reactively only when the component is rerendered

Comment: What about having the computed property change a data value. Then you can watch that data value?

Comment: Im fairly new to vuejs could you please provided an example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [watch computed properties in vuejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175998/watch-computed-properties-in-vuejs)