# watch computed properties in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to watch my computed property `isEllipsisActive()` to see if the value is true or false and then I would like to set `shouldShowArrow` to this value.

The value will changed when the user resizes their browser based on the condition `this.wrap.scrollHeight < this.h1.scrollHeight;`,

Currently it works but only if I refresh the browser, I need it to update when value changes.
How can I watch if the value of `isEllipsisActive()` changes?

```
export default {
  data() {
    return { 
      h1: null,
      wrap: null,
      shouldShowArrow: false,
    };
  },
    isEllipsisActive() {
      if (!this.wrap && !this.h1) {
        console.log("Not initialized", 'not initalized');
        return false;
      }
      return this.wrap.scrollHeight < this.h1.scrollHeight;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.h1 = this.$refs.h1;
      this.wrap = this.$refs.wrap;
    });
  },
  watch: {
    isEllipsisActive(newValue) {
      this.h1 !== null && console.log('changed')
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Computed itself is dynamic and you need not use a watch to monitor it's execution

Comment: You can make `shouldShowArrow` a computed property that depends on the value of `isEllipsisActive`, you don't need to manually watch it.

Comment: The basic concept behind its dynamicity is if the value of the variable used in the computed property changes then it will dynamically rerun

Comment: So I'm your case if this.h1 or this.wrap changes then automatically the computed property will rerun..no doubt in that

Answer (score 0):

You can’t “watch” a computed value because a computed value is already dynamic.

If you want to perform some logic basic on a computed value, then just use it to do so:

```html
<h1 v-if="isEllipsisActive">{{ title }}</h1>
```

You don’t need to “watch” your computed value just to set yet another boolean.

Comment: You can, and there is often good reason to do so.  Here, probably not

Comment: @Dan Reasons such as…?

Comment: The most common reason would probably be to fire off an async request.  But ultimately, for any reason you might watch a data property, you might watch a computed instead

Comment: The @Dan Reason is valid, for example, if you user Vuex getters, sometimes you need to do extra stuff when the getter trigger. 
Like this getter `getUsers` returns all users but at the same time in your component, you want to trigger `async FindMoviesByUsers`. So you watch when your getter change or trigger a change and your watch launch the `async FindMoviesByUsers`, something like this.

Comment: this doesn't work it is not reactive, unless it is rerendered

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way and see if trigger the watch for you

```
watch: {
  isEllipsisActive: {
     deep: true
     handler(now){
        this.h1 !== null && console.log('changed')
     }
}
```

since your computed value is in the same component that you are trying to watch the change performed you should not need to do that. Or you can watch one of the values and perform all the logic you need inside the watcher. But As @Dan say in another comment, sometimes we need to watch those computed values. I use this logic when I want to execute extra code after the computed getter from Vuex trigger changes.